# How to trigger a method to start at a certain?

Tags: java

I need a piece of code to start whenever it it 11 AM everyday. I do not want to use windows task manager or any other external things to start my app.

I need my app to trigger my method whenever it is time, 11 AM.
I have the following questions:

1) Is there any "Time Listener" (similar to action listener) that would do that

2) Is it ok if my app is always runs without closing

Comment: `java.util.Timer` - You may want to consider what to do if your system restarts.  If you're using something like `Timer`, the CPU load is relatively low to nonexistent

Comment: Check out Quartz scheduler

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer .  I heard about java.util.Timer. I am curious is there any hidden threat while the app stays idle in between the tasks execution? My computer will get locked .. but never shut down

Comment: Spring integration with Quartz is a good thing too, makes it so easy, just annotate a method and that's it.

Comment: Well some memory usage of course, and that can be lots of memory usage if your application leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, you can use the Timer class in java (java.util.Timer) or for finer control the Quartz library (that library uses the Unix cron style).

And yes it is ok if your app runs without closing. You can run it at the background but you might be better adding notification icon in the taskbar to ensure the user can find your app when they need to.

Comment: if you're going to leave your app running in the background to make sure you don't have any memory leaks or you could run into trouble

Comment: if we are using timers, if you have some sort of outage window, schedule a service restart.